# Spring drastically slows down score evaluation speed of Optaplanner solver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, optaplanner

I have a following piece of code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);

        OptimalTerminationTimeFinder.findOptimalTerminationTime(
            8,
            10,
            50,
            Duration.ofSeconds(1),
            Duration.ofMillis(250));
}
```

where `OptimalTerminationFinder` solves hundreds of problems and tries to find the best termination time for a given problem size.

The problem is that when I comment the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`, the score evaluation speed increases from 40k to 80k and vice versa.

Why is Spring slowing down the solver so much? I read the [user guide](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#springBootJavaQuickStart) for Spring and the only difference is that they use a `SolverManager` but that's not the problem, is it? I just use the `Solver` class.

I cannot afford such a drastic speed decrease with Spring - the time difference is crucial at the production.

Comment: If performance is critical to your use case, you might want to consider using Quarkus instead of Spring Boot. optaplanner-quarkus has some extra optimizations that Spring Boot doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure you're comparing apples to apples? Same solver duration, same dataset, same garbage collector, same max heap size, same logging (level + output), same JDK version and same machine? **There is no reason why the score calculation speed in Spring would be lower than in plain Java** (any bootstrap magic - including classpath scanning - does not affect the score calculation speed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the performance difference with [java-spring-boot](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/technology/java-spring-boot) quickstart.

I believe the slower calculation speed is somehow caused by [running the application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.7/reference/html/using.html#using.running-your-application) using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (I assume the plugin is also used by your IDE if you try to run a `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class).

If you first [build an executable JAR](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.7/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging) of your project and then run the JAR either in your IDE or from the terminal using `java -jar ...`, you'll see the full speed score calculation.

I don't have an explanation of why the Spring Boot Maven Plugin prevents full performance but the production build of your application won't suffer from that.

Comment: I can confirm that the executable jar seems to run at maximum speed. The production is unaffected by the performance decrease.

Answer (score 1):

I bet **it's the logging**. They probably differ by default between spring and plain java (so Yurloc's answer is correct). Check the logging levels and appenders for both runs.

I've seen the score calculation speed drop by a factor of 2x or more:

- Category  `org.optaplanner` from `DEBUG` to `TRACE` logging can be a 4x drop. It depends.
- Category  `org.optaplanner` from `INFO` to `DEBUG` logging can be a 2x drop. It depends.
- Category `org.drools` from `WARN` to `DEBUG` can be a 10x drop. It depends.
- Appender from `console` to `file` logging can be a 2x drop. It depends.